# JWT is not set in header

Tags: spring, angular, authentication

I'm following [this tutorial](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part2/), currently I can log in and out with a user but when a user logs in the JWT token isn't send with the header request (I think) so I get a 401 after the `router.navigate`. When I reload the page I can use the token and everything works.

In my login.component.ts I have this login function:

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(result => {
            if (result === true) {
                // login successful
                this.router.navigate(['home']);
            } else {
                // login failed
                this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                this.loading = false;
            }
        }, error => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.error = error;
        });
}
```

This calls the login function in the authentication.service.ts:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), {headers: this.headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            const token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                // return true to indicate successful login
                alert('Success');
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                alert('Fail');
                return false;
            }
        }).catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

If the login is successful the user is routed to /home:

```
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

In the home.component.ts I have a getAll function that returns all movies in the database:

```
getAll() {
  this._dataService
    .getAll<Movie[]>()
    .subscribe((data: any[]) => this.movies = data,
    error => () => {
        'something went wrong';
    },
    () => {
        console.log(this.movies);
    });
}
```

This function is called on the ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getAll();
}
```

In my app.service.ts I have the get function:

```
public getAll<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    if (this.authenticationService.getToken()) {
        console.log(this.authenticationService.getToken());
        console.log(this.headers);
        return this.http.get<T[]>('/api/movies/all', {headers: this.headers});
    }
}
```

But when I log in I get this error after being routed to the home page:

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/movies/all 401 (Unauthorized)

The problem (I think) is that when I get routed to the home page the header is missing the token. But as you can see from the console log the token is available in app.service.ts.

[image]

When I reload the page I do have the token set in the header and everything works:

[image]

Any ideas on how to expose the token to the header after the redirect?

//EDIT

For some reason I do get the JWT token when I set the header directly in the function:

```
    return this.http.get<T[]>('/api/movies/all', {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.getToken())});
```

Instead of calling it like this:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.getToken());

    return this.http.get('/api/movies/' + id, {headers: this.headers});
```

Comment: Where do you call the `headers = new HttpHeaders...` function as it would appear that you have a race condition between that call and your get call. You'd need to make the get rely on the headers finishing by do an observable here or some such if  this can chain out of order.